# jquery load gets no result

Tags: php, jquery, html, parameters

I am fighting with a jquery load thing that is supposed to load some comments into my comments area.

I use this

```
$("#designCommentsBox").load("pullcomment.php");
```

and my pullcomment.php looks like this:

```
<?php
define("INCLUDE_DIR", "includes/classes");

/* Autoload classes when used */
function __autoload($class_name) { include(INCLUDE_DIR.'/class.'. strtolower($class_name) . '.php'); } 

SQLHandling::SQLconnect();
Designs::GetCommentsForDesign(1); //Default value for testing
?>
```

And the function GetCommentsForDesign is this:

```
function GetCommentsForDesign($design_id) {
        $sql = SQLHandling::selectSQL('*', 'tdic_comments', 'design_id = '. $design_id .'');
        $result = SQLHandling::SQLquery($sql);            

        $markers = array();


        $markers["###NUM_COMMENTS###"] = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
            $markers["###COMMENTS###"] = "No comments";           
        } else { 

        while($row = SQLHandling::SQLfetch($result)) {
            $markers["###COMMENTS###"] = '<div class="commentBox">';
                $markers["###COMMENTS###"] .= '<div class="commentLeft"><img src="ss.jpg" /></div>';
                $markers["###COMMENTS###"] .= '<div class="commentRight">';

                    if(!empty($row["website"])) {
                        $markers["###COMMENTS###"] .= '<span class="commentPoster"><a href="'. $row["website"] .'" target="_blank" rel="external nofollow">'. $row["name"] .'</a></span>';    
                    } else {
                        $markers["###COMMENTS###"] .= '<span class="commentPoster">'. $row["name"] .'</span>'; 
                    }
                    $markers["###COMMENTS###"] .= '<br /><span class="commentDate">'. date('d-m-Y', $row["date_added"]) .'</span>';    
                    $markers["###COMMENTS###"] .= '<p class="comment">'. $row["comment"] .'</p>';
                $markers["###COMMENTS###"] .= '</div>';
            $markers["###COMMENTS###"] .= '</div>';
        }
        }
        Main::GetMarkers($markers);

    }
```

The load is supposed to load all comments into to this but I am not getting anything

```
<div id="designCommentsBox">
</div>
```

What is weird that if I f.x. do an echo `$row["comment"]` inside the GetCommentsForDesign function, that comment do get printed out.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

A secondary question
How can I pass an URL parameter into to load? Like this

```
$("#designCommentsBox").load("pullcomment.php?designid=1"); //From the URL
```

And then pass that param into the function?

Comment: That just put all my data in $markers into another file.

Comment: I can not see where is the `echo` to print the result on screen. Maybe you need a `echo $markers["###COMMENTS###"];` before closing `GetCommentsForDesign` function.

Comment: You need to return $markers. Then in the load you can do function(data) and work with the returned data. because it will be an array you cannot alert it but you can console.log it.

Comment: Fong-Wan Chau - Can you make an answer? ... I echo'ed the markers and voila! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind! I had some bad javascript further dowm my site! With that gone, everything is in order! Sorry!